# Arduino SoftwareSerial library mod to allow 8-O-1 com

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to use Arduino's SoftwareSerial to communicate with a RS-422 device.
I use [SN75179BP](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75179b.pdf) to convert 422 to TTL.

The device is 8bit - odd parity - 1 stop bit.
I've tried to mod the softwareserial library using:
http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,108097.0.html

Changed the parity bit calculation in the write function to odd instead of even.

Couple of problems:
First, if I use the exact mod suggested by pylon [the 4th comment] on the recv function, while trying to upload the sketch I get:

```
/var/folders/st/vmhkh5t57592ln_zhkyfq2q80000gn/T//cct5EjNP.s: Assembler messages:
/var/folders/st/vmhkh5t57592ln_zhkyfq2q80000gn/T//cct5EjNP.s:243: Error: register r24, r26, r28 or r30 required
/var/folders/st/vmhkh5t57592ln_zhkyfq2q80000gn/T//cct5EjNP.s:263: Error: register r24, r26, r28 or r30 required
```

Have no idea why. 
but if I leave the function as is, and only changing this:

```
  // skip the parity bit
    tunedDelay(_rx_delay_stopbit);
    DebugPulse(_DEBUG_PIN2, 1);

    // skip the stop bit
    tunedDelay(_rx_delay_stopbit);
    DebugPulse(_DEBUG_PIN2, 1);
```

to this:

```
 // skip the 2 stop bits
    tunedDelay(_rx_delay_stopbit*2);
    DebugPulse(_DEBUG_PIN2, 1);
```

I can upload the sketch and even start receiving true and correct data on my serial.

The second problem, is that no matter what I do - I can't get the write function to work.
The device doesn't respond to any input except that in the second I try to send something to that device over the serial, I stop getting nice and clean data on my recieve channel, instead I get clutter...

[BTW, in that situation - if send some "new line" 0D, it brings back the normal data on the recieve channel...]

*-I'm using Arduino 1.0.1

EDIT: I don't know if it's important or not, but I'm using inverse_logic for the receive function to work.

Any ideas will be more than welcome!

Comment: Solution: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,122281.0.html

Comment: It would be nice if you could answer your own question. Including the link is fine, but since link-only answers are frowned upon because of link-rot, be sure to add a short summary in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the write function to non-inverse logic and ensuring that you've set up the parity and stop bit correctly? :-)